# Where exactly is the night market in Jinghong, Xishuangbanna (China)?

Tags: food-and-drink, nightlife, local-cuisine, locate-this, yunnan

[WikiTravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Jinghong) and [WikiVoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Jinghong) both mention that there's a night market with lots of street food here in Jinghong, the capital of the [Xishuangbanna Dai Autonomous Prefecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xishuangbanna_Dai_Autonomous_Prefecture) in southern Yunnan.

I've been keen to try some food of the Dai minority since they're related to the Lao and Thai peoples and it's said that some is available at the night market.

But tonight I couldn't find the night market. Has it been done away with? Has it moved? Is the information about its location in those websites just not clear enough for a dummy like me to follow?

It's supposedly in Xishuangbanna Park on the right side of the new bridge.

But there are several parks and none seem to have this exact name.

And there are two bridges and not much indication of which is the "new" one.

And "right" is a relative direction. Where should I stand and which direction should I face for it to be on my right?

I was at [Binjiang Park](http://www.google.cn/maps/place/Binjiang+Park,+Jinghong,+Xishuangbanna,+Yunnan,+666101/@22.0075719,100.8041981,17z/data=!4m6!1m3!3m2!1s0x312aa37ebba46363:0x2daa188a2647b3dc!2z6KW_5Y-M54mI57qz5ZiO5rSS5Zu96ZmF5py65Zy6!3m1!1s0x312abb33dae7b9af:0x93abb1847876d662) because it was next to a bridge. There were a few people and a couple of amusements for the kids but no night market and no food stalls.

There was a big new-looking plaza with a lot more happening just a bit to the south. But I didn't see street food stalls there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to an online [index of the markets etc there](http://www.mekongcafe.cn/jinghong%20Xishuangbanna%20what%20to%20do%20what%20to%20see.html):

> There is also a night market (J13 on the map)where Thai, Lao, Burmese
>   and local items can be found; starts daily at 8pm.

[Here is a link to the map](http://www.mekongcafe.cn/detailed%20jinghong%20map.html) - sorry, I couldn't really convert it into a format here easily without pilfering it directly - if you find a way, feel free to update.

Comment: Ah so it looks like it has indeed moved. Nice find!